# List will be adjusted when add baritem in swift-ui/xcode12

Tags: swiftui

I just try this code but I got unexpected edge for List.
If I remove navigationBarItems everything is ok.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

let numbers: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

struct NavBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                SimpleRow(title: number)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Numbers"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { // add this will affect the List position and size

            }, label: {Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.medium)}
            ))
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleRow: View {
    var title: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting behavior, as it is only when modifier applied directly to List... even can't say if it is a bug... Maybe it is because `navigationBarItems` has deprecated.

Anyway here is possible solution - attach navigation bar items to something else, like background.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct NavBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                SimpleRow(title: number)
            }
            .background(Color.clear
               .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {

               }, label: {Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.medium)}
            )))
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Numbers"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reminder. It sounds like using Toolbar to replace navigationBarItems from Apple.